# Errors in IE 11 after `Ember new`, app does not serve (Ember 3.1.2)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

After creating a fresh application using `ember new ietest --no-welcome` and executing `ember serve` without modifying any code, the Ember app loads fine in Chrome and IE Edge but doesn't load in IE 11 and yields two errors:

- `Syntax Error at vendor.js (64292,18)`
- `Expected Identifier at ietest.js (32,9)`

[error console shortlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGj38.png)

[error console details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bexUb.png)

The page is blank, it doesn't even display "Welcome to Ember". The errors also occur if I leave off `--no-welcome`. In that case, the hamster page doesn't appear.

ember-cli version: 3.1.2

OS: Windows 10

Any way to fix this? Perhaps a setting in IE11 that I can toggle?

Comment: please add your console errors and details as code in your question and not as links to images.

Comment: Ember 3.x supports IE11 in the production build, but not in the development build. You can adjust `config/targets.js` if you want to support IE11 in the development build.

Comment: @mwp That did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `config/targets.js` add the following to the `browsers` property array:

```
'ie 11',
```

Quote @mwp above:

> Ember 3.x supports IE11 in the production build, but not in the
>   development build. You can adjust config/targets.js if you want to
>   support IE11 in the development build.